# How to implement Google Analytics with NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js, google-analytics

```
//GoogleAnalytics.tsx

"use client";
import Script from "next/script";

const GoogleAnalytics = ({ GA_TRACKING_ID }: { GA_TRACKING_ID: string }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
      <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', ${GA_TRACKING_ID});
        `}
      </Script>
    </>
  );
};

export default GoogleAnalytics;
```

```
//layout.tsx

import GoogleAnalytics from "@/components/molecules/GoogleAnalytics";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <GoogleAnalytics GA_TRACKING_ID={process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID} />
      <body>      
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

With this code, the script tags are properly filled with my ID G-XXXXXXX.
[image: scripts tags]

However, I get a "G is not defined" error in browser console when loading the page.

```
VM689:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: G is not defined
    at <anonymous>:6:26
    at loadScript (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.2.4_dpxg4zawgzznnxdt7it3f5d76m/node_modules/next/dist/client/script.js:91:19)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.2.4_dpxg4zawgzznnxdt7it3f5d76m/node_modules/next/dist/client/script.js:182:17)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.2.4_dpxg4zawgzznnxdt7it3f5d76m/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26416:26)
```

I have already tried placing GoogleAnalytics tag in the body, and also in the head.tsx. Same error.

Comment: I believe the env variable should be named NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID

Comment: Is there any reason to pass the GA ID as props? Can i use it directly in the `GoogleAnalytics.tsx` file?

Comment: Do you still need to ask for pageViews, or does this do that in effect?

Answer (score 22):

I found what "G is not defined" stands for.
G is actually the first letter of the tracking ID.
By using template strings here, I didn't realize that the final code was wrong. I am not importing a string here, but literally the tracking ID which is therefore considered a variable.
[image]

To solve the problem, I simply added quotes :

```
gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}');
```

Comment: Dude, you saved me much time in debugging! Thanks

Comment: This is a really nice solution for adding Analytics, nice one man.

Comment: thanks!  same mistake easily made if using an env var

Comment: Thanks @Flaviean Laureau. This was stumping me for too long

Answer (score 2):

Found this question while searching on how to implement Google analytics in NextJS project with app directory. The code in the question works fine in my project with only type error. To avoid this, need to tell TypeScript that we are sure the value is defined and a string.

```
// app/GoogleAnalytics.tsx

 "use client";
import Script from "next/script";

const GoogleAnalytics = ({ GA_TRACKING_ID }: { GA_TRACKING_ID: string }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
      <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', "${GA_TRACKING_ID}");
        `}
      </Script>
    </>
  );
};

export default GoogleAnalytics;
```

assuming your environment variable is set as below including G- prefix:

```
// .env.local
GA_TRACKING_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXX


// app/layout.tsx        
import GoogleAnalytics from "./GoogleAnalytics";
        ...
            return (
        <html lang="en">
          <GoogleAnalytics GA_TRACKING_ID={process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID as string} />
          <body>
            <Header />
            {children}
          </body>
        </html>
      );
        ...
```

Could also use the following method, useful when you dont want to track your localhost activities. This way if *GA_TRACKING_ID* is not defined, the component will not be rendered.

```
...
{process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID && (
        <GoogleAnalytics GA_TRACKING_ID={process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID} />
      )}
    ...
```