# Google analytics with nextjs 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-analytics, next.js13

has anyone successfully gotten google analytics to work on NextJS 13?

I've followed this thread: [How to implement Google Analytics with NextJS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749102/how-to-implement-google-analytics-with-nextjs-13) but when I do the same thing on my app, nothing shows up on Google Analytics.  I also don't get any errors within the app and the script loads correctly when I inspect the page.

I want to comment in that thread above but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Let me know if you learn anything.

Answer (score 7):

Here is full code for Google Analytics on Next.JS 13

install gtag

```
npm install @types/gtag.js
```

on `.env.production`

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID="G-XXXXXXXXX"
```

on `@/lib/gtag.ts`

```
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const GA_TRACKING_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID;

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages
export const pageview = (url: URL) => {
  window.gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID as string, {
    page_path: url,
  });
};

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events
export const event = (
  action: Gtag.EventNames,
  { event_category, event_label, value }: Gtag.EventParams,
) => {
  window.gtag('event', action, {
    event_category,
    event_label,
    value,
  });
};

export const useGtag = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname(); // Get current route

  // Save pathname on component mount into a REF
  const savedPathNameRef = useRef(pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') return;

    const handleRouteChange = (url: URL) => {
      pageview(url);
    };

    if (savedPathNameRef.current !== pathname) {
      handleRouteChange(new URL(pathname, window.location.origin));
      // Update REF
      savedPathNameRef.current = pathname;
    }
  }, [pathname, ]);
};
```

on `components/GoogleAnalytics.tsx`

```
'use client'

import Script from 'next/script';
import * as gtag from '@/lib/gtag';

export default function GoogleAnalytics(){

    gtag.useGtag();

    return (
        <>
            {process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && (
            <>
                {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
                <Script
                strategy="afterInteractive"
                src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${gtag.GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
                />
                <Script
                id="gtag-init"
                strategy="afterInteractive"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                    gtag('js', new Date());
                    gtag('config', '${gtag.GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
                        page_path: window.location.pathname,
                    });
                    `,
                }}
                />
            </>
            )} 
        </>
    )
}
```

on `app/layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
    <html lang="ko">
        <GoogleAnalytics />
        <body>
                {children}
        </body>
    </html>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: is this for Google Analytics 4? Or Universal Analytics? Comment on `@/lib/gtag.ts`, `// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events` refers to UA docs. Just wondering if it'll work with A4.

Answer (score 1):

inside `app/layout.tsx` file, write:

```
import Script from 'next/script' 
      
<Script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<G-mytag>" strategy="afterInteractive"
                        id='ga_analytics' />

<Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
       {`
         window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
         function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
         gtag('js', new Date());
         gtag('config', 'G-mytag');
         `}
</Script>
```

Note: This method is tested with 5+ websites of my clients and works perfectly on every site.  I am using nextjs 13.5 + with app-router for  all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Next docs.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-report-web-vitals#sending-results-to-external-systems

and

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#send-the-results-to-google-analytics

Answer (score 0):

After successfuly setting up the analytics config like the OP does here:

[How to implement Google Analytics with NextJS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749102/how-to-implement-google-analytics-with-nextjs-13)

You can test it by triggering a simple event, like this:

`app/components/GoogleAnalyticsEvent.js`

```
'use client'
import Script from "next/script"

const GoogleAnalyticsEvent = () => {

    return (
        <Script 
            id="google-analytics-event"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
        >
            {`gtag('event', 'this_is_my_test', {
                'app_name': 'myAppName',
                'screen_name': 'Home'
                });`
            }
        </Script>
    )
}
export default GoogleAnalyticsEvent
```

and this is how your `app/layout.js` should look like:

```
import GoogleAnalyticsInit from './components/GoogleAnalyticsInit';
import GoogleAnalyticsEvent from './components/GoogleAnalyticsEvent';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <GoogleAnalyticsInit />
        <GoogleAnalyticsEvent />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And, going to the Google Analytics Dashboard (Reports > Realtime tab > (Event count by Event name)), you could visualize your test being show, after refreshing the page in your local:

[image: Analytics dashboard print screen]

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration for Next.js 13.4 and Google Analytics 4.

Add this to RootPage:

```
<Script
    src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
/>
<Script id="google-analytics">
    {`
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}');

    `}
</Script>
```

Replace the environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_GA_MEASUREMENT_ID with your own GA4 tag.

Comment: On vercel getting window undefined